# How to deal with coupled equations of motions in equilibrium analysis?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, equilibrium, coupled-oscillators

Consider a system including two generalized coordinates $q_1$ and $q_2$ whose dynamics is supposed to be obtained using first-kind Euler-Lagrange (E-L) formalism

$$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q_{i}}} - \frac{\partial L}{\partial q_{i}} = 0 \quad (i=\{1,2\}),$$

where $L$ denotes the Lagrangian of the system.

The final goal is the analysis of the equilibrium points of the system at which all derivatives of the cited coordinates have to vanish. In relatively simple systems, e.g., mass-spring system, the dynamics of coordinates are obtained in a decoupled manner as follows

$$\ddot{q_1} = f(q_{1},q_{2},\dot{q_{1}},\dot{q_{2}}),$$
$$\ddot{q_2} = g(q_{1},q_{2},\dot{q_{1}},\dot{q_{2}}),$$

for some functions $f$ and $g$.

But (E-L) strategy may return coupled equations in the case of complex systems, say,

$$f(q_{1},q_{2},\dot{q_{1}},\dot{q_{2}},\ddot{q_1},\ddot{q_2}) = 0,$$
$$g(q_{1},q_{2},\dot{q_{1}},\dot{q_{2}},\ddot{q_1},\ddot{q_2}) = 0.$$

Again, $f$ and $g$ are assumed to be some generally nonlinear functions.

In a particular application which includes very complex coupled equations, I need to find the system's equilibria, however when I pick zero values for the derivative terms in the equations, everything vanishes and I end up with two (trivial) $0=0$ identities. In other words, what I expect to yield is non-trivial expressions of $q_1$ and $q_2$ to represent the (potential) equilibria. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in principle impossible about a system being in equilibrium at every point given that the initial conditions are specified such that the system is initially not in motion. If the Euler-Lagrange equations are satisfied in all such cases, it means that at least up to first order, these represent legitimate extremal points of the action functional, and thus are legitimate physical trajectories, again up to first order.

It's of course possible that the naive first order analysis of the Euler-Lagrange equations misidentifies some configurations as being extremal when they in fact are not, similar to what happens at $ x = 0 $ for $ x \to x^3 $, for instance. In that case you need to do higher order perturbation analysis of the action functional, similar to looking at the third derivative of $ x \to x^3 $ to see it's nonzero at $ x = 0 $, and thus the point can't represent a local extremum.

Comment: Sorry but I can't completely follow your point. In particular, can you explain what you mean by "legitimate trajectories"?

Comment: By the way, what do you mean by "up to the first order"? These equations include 2nd-order terms if you note.

Comment: @Roboticist That's not what I'm talking about. The Euler-Lagrange equations are first order conditions on the optimization of the action functional - they are equivalent to setting the first order variation in the action to zero. That's different from the action incorporating higher order derivative terms in the Lagrangian. If you're unfamiliar with this, check how the Euler-Lagrange equations are derived on Wikipedia, or consult your favorite calculus of variations text.

Comment: I know what the E-L equations are, but your explanations do not address my question.

Comment: @Roboticist As for "legitimate trajectory", I simply mean $ q_1, q_2 $ can indeed be functions that locally minimize the action whenever they are constant over time, for instance; as is the case for the free particle Lagrangian in space.

Comment: @Roboticist My explanation does address your question. You're computing the first order variation in the action and you find it vanishes whenever $ q_1, q_2 $ have zero first derivative. That could mean these are in fact real stationary states of the system, or they could simply appear as such because the first order analysis of the Euler-Lagrange equation is insufficient to decide the issue, in which case you need higher order perturbations to see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Lets look at this example:

**Double Pendulum**

with the position vector to mass one and two

$$\vec{R}_1= \left[ \begin {array}{c} \rho\,\cos \left( q_{{1}} \right) 
\\ \rho\,\sin \left( q_{{1}} \right) \end {array}
 \right]  
$$

$$\vec{R}_2=\left[ \begin {array}{c} \rho\,\cos \left( q_{{1}} \right) +\rho\,
\cos \left( q_{{2}} \right) \\ \rho\,\sin \left( q_{
{1}} \right) +\rho\,\sin \left( q_{{2}} \right) \end {array} \right] 
$$

you get with EL the EOM's:

$$m{\rho}^{2} \left( {\frac {d}{d\tau}}q_{{2}} \left( \tau \right) 
 \right) ^{2}\sin \left( q_{{1}} \left( \tau \right) -q_{{2}} \left( 
\tau \right)  \right) +2\,mg\rho\,\cos \left( q_{{1}} \left( \tau
 \right)  \right) +m{\rho}^{2} \left( 2\,{\frac {d^{2}}{d{\tau}^{2}}}q
_{{1}} \left( \tau \right) + \left( {\frac {d^{2}}{d{\tau}^{2}}}q_{{2}
} \left( \tau \right)  \right) \cos \left( q_{{1}} \left( \tau
 \right) -q_{{2}} \left( \tau \right)  \right)  \right) 
=0\tag 1$$

and

$$-m{\rho}^{2} \left( {\frac {d}{d\tau}}q_{{1}} \left( \tau \right) 
 \right) ^{2}\sin \left( q_{{1}} \left( \tau \right) -q_{{2}} \left( 
\tau \right)  \right) +mg\rho\,\cos \left( q_{{2}} \left( \tau
 \right)  \right) +m{\rho}^{2} \left(  \left( {\frac {d^{2}}{d{\tau}^{
2}}}q_{{1}} \left( \tau \right)  \right) \cos \left( q_{{1}} \left( 
\tau \right) -q_{{2}} \left( \tau \right)  \right) +{\frac {d^{2}}{d{
\tau}^{2}}}q_{{2}} \left( \tau \right)  \right)
=0\tag 2$$

for ${\frac {d^{2}}{d{\tau}^{2}}}q_{{i}} \left( \tau \right)=0\quad,{\frac {d}{d\tau}}q_{{i}} \left( \tau \right)=0
 \quad i=1,2$

thus equation(1) and (2)

$$2\,mg\rho\,\cos \left( q_{{1}} \right)=0$$
$$mg\rho\,\cos \left( q_{{2}} \right)=0$$

so you get the equilibrium for $q_1=\pi/2\quad,q_2=\pi/2$

and your position vectors are:

$$\vec{R}_1=\left[ \begin {array}{c} 0\\ \rho\end {array}
 \right] 
$$ 
$$\vec{R}_2=\left[ \begin {array}{c} 0\\ 2\,\rho\end {array}
 \right] 
$$

**edit**

spring mass system

[image]

the EOM's are:

$$m_1\ddot{q}_1+{\it c1}\, \left( q_{{1}}-q_{{2}}-l_{{1}} \right) +{\it c3}\, \left( q
_{{1}}-l_{{3}} \right) =0
$$
$$m_2\ddot{q}_2+{\it c2}\, \left( q_{{2}}-l_{{2}} \right) -{\it c1}\, \left( q_{{1}}-q
_{{2}}-l_{{1}} \right) =0
$$

where $c_il_1$   are the pre-
load forces

with $\ddot{q}_i=0$ you get the equilibrium

$$q_1={\frac {{\it c1}\,{\it c2}\,l_{{2}}+{\it c1}\,{\it c3}\,l_{{3}}+{\it 
c2}\,{\it c3}\,l_{{3}}+{\it c2}\,{\it c1}\,l_{{1}}}{{\it c1}\,{\it c2}
+{\it c3}\,{\it c2}+{\it c1}\,{\it c3}}}
$$

$$q_2={\frac {{\it c1}\,{\it c2}\,l_{{2}}+{\it c1}\,{\it c3}\,l_{{3}}+{\it 
c3}\,{\it c2}\,l_{{2}}-{\it c1}\,l_{{1}}{\it c3}}{{\it c1}\,{\it c2}+{
\it c3}\,{\it c2}+{\it c1}\,{\it c3}}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

The specific example you give of a spring-mass system is a natural system for which $2T=\sum \dot{q}p$ and, if the coordinates $q_i$ measure a departure from equilibrium, then $q_i=0$ are the equilibrium positions, just as you find.

The equation of motion for $q_i$ should not depend on the velocities $\dot{q}_k$ unless you have friction since
$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q_i}}$ should be proportional to $\dot{q}_i$ itself, and $\frac{\partial L}{\partial q_i}$ should be linear in the coordinates.

In a more general setting, the stable points are given in terms of Hamiltonian of the system $H=\sum p\dot{q}-L$, with $\dot{q}$ inverted to give $H$ in terms of $p$ and $q$ alone.  Then the equilibrium position are obtained by $\vec\nabla H=0$.

If the system is a natural system so that $H=T+V$, then $\vec \nabla H=0$ produces $p=0$ and $\frac{\partial V}{\partial q}=0$ as expected.  If the system is not natural, i.e. $H\ne T+V$, then you may have solutions with $p=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}\ne 0$ which, when inverted, might give non-trivial relations.